# Rogue node in RabbitMQ cluster

Tags: cookies, rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ cluster with 3 nodes. All nodes are running as a service. I have synced up all the 6 erlang cookies to be only one. I ran into an issue with one of the nodes. In the management plugin the node shows up online and working. If I want to stop it in the CLI however, I am told that erlang refused connection and that I should check the cookie to be the same.

The cookie were indeed different so I fixed that.

Question #1: Why/when did the cookie get changed, or when does a new cookie get created? ( I had previously synced the cookies up)

Question #2: Why did the node show as running in the management plugin but the erlang distribution failed in the CLI?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this link:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html

The section:

```
Copy the file .erlang.cookie manually from %SystemRoot% to  %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.
```

In your system you have 2 `.erlang.cookie` files, the one inside `%SystemRoot%` is used by the service the second one `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` is used by the command line.

just copy the file from `%SystemRoot%` to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` and the command line will work

Comment: I realized that the two cookies were different and fixed that. But that wasn't my question. Sorry I wasn't clear on it. I'll edit the question.